# MVVMCross documentation needs updating for latest release?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm very new to MVVMCross and I was following the TipCalc tutorial however it seems it was written for an older version MVVMCross. I'm stuck in the [TipCalc Android Project](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarinandroid-ui-project) section because the MvvmCross package doesnt have a class called `MvxAndroidApplication`.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core; // this namespace doesn't exist
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views;
using TipCalc.Core;

namespace TipCalc.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : MvxAndroidApplication<MvxAndroidSetup<App>, App>
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Android version in the Project settings. Details in this link https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/3958